# Can't avoid null key errors when filtering by items in nested list

Tags: jq

My json looks like this:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "topLevelField":{
            "i-want-this":"some-value1"
         },
         "nestedFieldTop":{
            "nestedField":[
               {
                  "name":"key1",
                  "value":"val1"
               },
               {
                  "name":"key2",
                  "value":"val2"
               },
               {
                  "name":"key3",
                  "someOtherProperty":"sdfsdfdsf"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "topLevelField":{
            "i-want-this":"some-value2"
         },
         "nestedFieldTop":{
            "nestedField":[
               {
                  "name":"key1",
                  "value":"vala"
               },
               {
                  "name":"keyb",
                  "value":"valb"
               },
               {
                  "name":"key3",
                  "someOtherProperty":"sdfsdfdsf"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to filter out objects in the items list that have an object in their nestedField array where `name == key1` and `value == vala`.
The problem is that the value field doesn't exist for all nestedField objects.

This is so close to what I want. In this example I'm trying to return only the object where `nestedField[].name == "key1"` and `nestedField[].value == "vala"`:

```
cat mydata.json | \
    jq '.items[] | select(.nestedFieldTop.nestedField[] | has("value")) | select((.nestedFieldTop.nestedField[].name | contains("key1")) and (.nestedFieldTop.nestedField[].value | contains("vala")))'
```

Snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/Oqau-oui5O0

I was trying to have the first select `select(.nestedFieldTop.nestedField[] | has("value"))` only pass along the nested objects that have a `value` field to the other select statements. This doesn't work because it's passing the *full* objects and I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:17385): null (null) and string ("vala...) cannot have their containment checked`

I do want to return the full objects, but I need some way of doing a nested select statement against the objects of the `nestedFields`.

Comment: Your sample data is not valid JSON.  Please fix.  Also, please follow the [mcve] guidelines and show what your desired output would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
jq '.items[] |
    select(any(.nestedFieldTop.nestedField[];
               .name == "key1" and .value == "vala"
              )
          )' mydata.json
```

From https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition) :

The `any(generator; condition)` form applies the given condition to all the outputs of the given generator.

Comment: Perfect! Would it be possible to explain what this is doing? Specifically `any` and the semicolon. I'm going through the docs myself, but if you could also explain that would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After modifying your sample data in what seems to me the most obvious way, I came up with the following interpretation of your question:

```
  map(.nestedFieldTop |=
        (.nestedField |= map( select( .name == "key1" and .value == "vala") ) ))
```

With the modified sample data, this produces:

```
[
  {
    "topLevelField": {
      "i-want-this": "some-value1"
    },
    "nestedFieldTop": {
      "nestedField": []
    }
  },
  {
    "topLevelField": {
      "i-want-this": "some-value2"
    },
    "nestedFieldTop": {
      "nestedField": [
        {
          "name": "key1",
          "value": "vala"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Updated my post with valid json